# How to specify Check Constraint on Varchar Datatype column in SQLALchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to specify this check constraint on a column via SQLAlchemy.

```
delete_flag char(1) not null CHECK(delete_flag in('Y','N')),
```

I am not able to figure out the syntax to achieve this. Any link, tutorial, advise will be of great help.

Thanks 
Tara Singh

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the [SQLAlchemy Enum type](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum) in this case.

```
import enum
from sqlalchemy import Enum

class YesNo(enum.Enum):
    yes = 'Y'
    no = 'N'

t = Table(
    'data', MetaData(),
    Column('value', Enum(YesNo, create_constraint=True))
)

connection.execute(t.insert(), {"value": YesNo.no})
assert connection.scalar(t.select()) is YesNo.no
```

[Check Constraint docs for completeness](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#check-constraint)

Comment: Docs aren't very clear here - what would the actual code look like which answers the posted question?

Comment: I've added the example, but it's literally the example from the docs with "one = 1, two = 2, three = 3" replaced with "yes = 'Y', no = 'N'" and create_constraint=True to create the constraint